# Mostrar información de una imagen concreta al hacer click en ella (PHP PDO y mySql)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy haciendo una web en la que muestro una galeria de fotografías con animales, y quería mostrar la información concreta de dicho animal cuando el usuario hiciese clic en el botón de detalles de la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, ya he conseguido que me muestre la información al hacer click en detalles pero me los muestra en forma array, como puedo hacer para que no se muestre de dicha forma? es decir que no aparezca  el nombre de las filas de la BD.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto aquí el código al que redirecciona el botón de detalles:

```
<?php
    require ('index.php');
    require "navegacion.php";
    //$vista = new Animales();
    //$mostrar = $vista->visualizar();
    
    // Si existe nombre y id lo obtiene a través del get
if (isset($_GET['nombre']) && isset($_GET['id'])) :
    // Obtenemos el nombre y el id
    $nombre_perro = $_GET['nombre']; 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // Obtienes datos desde la nueva función
    // Instanciamos el objeto
    $obj = new Animales();
    // Llamamos a la funcion
    $datos = $obj->visualizarById($id);
else:
    // si no existe parametros puedes redirecionar a la galeria
    //header("location: fotosAnimales.php");
endif;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssanimales.css">
 
</head>
<body>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>     
                    <?php
        // Muestra los datos
        echo '<pre>';
  
        print_r($datos);
        ?>
                    <<img src="<?php echo $datos->img;?>" alt="alt"/>
                    <?php
        echo '<pre>';
    ?>       
                   </div>
   
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Por que no imprimis los datos manualmente en lugar de usar `print_r`?

Comment: @Marcos a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Ejemplo: `<strong>Nombre: </strong> <?php echo $datos->nombre ?><br/>`, y así con el resto

Comment: @Marcos solucionado, muchas gracias! puedes  ponerlo como respuesta si quieres

Comment: Aparece así por la llamada `print_r();` que estas haciendo, si ya tienes los datos solo pintalos ya no es necesario el print()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de usar `print_r`, podrías imprimir los datos que deseas manualmente.

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <strong>Nombre: </strong> <?php echo $datos->nombre ?><br/>
        <strong>Raza: </strong> <?php echo $datos->raza ?><br/>
        <strong>Tamaño: </strong> <?php echo $datos->tamanyo ?><br/>
        <!-- etc.. -->
        <img src="<?php echo $datos->img;?>" alt="alt"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```